# Connect with SSH to AKS cluster nodes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssh, virtual-machine, azure-aks

I am trying to connect with SSH to a scale set-based AKS cluster node for maintenance purposes. I am following the instructions in this article:
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh`

However, when I run:
`az vmss extension set --name VMAccessForLinux --protected-settings '{\"username\":\"azureuser\", \"ssh_key\":\"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}' --publisher Microsoft.OSTCExtensions --resource-group $RG_NAME --version 1.4 --vmss-name $NODE_NAME`

I get the following error:
`VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'VMAccessForLinux'. Error message: "Enable failed: Failed to generate public key file.`

My SSH key pair is located at `C:\Users\username\.ssh` and readable. I have tried generating multiple pairs, but the issue does not seem to be here. For generating the keys I used: `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096`

Any idea where I can find more information about this error or how can I troubleshoot it in more detail? Thank you.

Comment: ssh_key supports ssh-rsa and .pem format.
If your public key is in .pem format, use the following link to convert the .pem file to a value that can be passed in a JSON string

https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/VMAccess#12-protected-configuration

Comment: the keys are definitely ssh-rsa format so I don't think that the problem is here. I just regenerated them with OpenSSH ssh-keygen command.

Comment: You are using command ssh-keygen -m PEM. This creates ssh key in PEM format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you need to use the double quotes to set the value of the parameter `--protected-setting like this:

```
--protected-settings "{\"username\":\"azureuser\", \"ssh_key\":\"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}"
```

Only when you use the double quotes then the character `\` can work. You need to read the document carefully. And make sure the SSH public key is in the right format.

Comment: I tried with double quotes before (like shows in their article) and I get: ```Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)```. The SSH public key has the correct format: ```ssh-rsa AAAA*****```

Comment: input: ```az vmss extension set --resource-group $RG --vmss-name $VM --name VMAccessForLinux --publisher Microsoft.OSTCExtensions --version 1.4 --protected-settings "{\"username\":\"azureuser\", \"ssh_key\":\"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}"```

   output: ```Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)```

Comment: @Poctan It seems you execute the CLI command in windows. All the commands this document showed are executed in the Linux OS.

Comment: @Poctan I recommend you execute the CLI command in Linux, the PowerShell command in Windows.

Comment: The article says use Azure CLI and that's what I did. I have also tried in Bash and I get the same initial error. Anyway, I think the issue is related to the cluster itself as I have just tried to use the extension on another cluster and it worked fine. Thank you very much for your help!